# not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, hierarchyid, ef-core-7.0

I updated my project from ef 6 to 7 and got this error

```
not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.
  Source=EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId
```

Comment: Update [EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId/4.0.0-rc.2)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You mean install it, because it doesn't exist. And it didn't work after installing it

Comment: If it exists if you check Include prerelease check box.

Comment: I had same issue on .net 7.0.4, I have added `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` nuget package to the project in addition to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

Answer (score 2):

Happened with me as well when i updated from .net5 to .net6, and updated my packages.

Uninstall 7.0 version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design and then

In NuGet package manager console, run

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -Version 6.0.10